# How can I debug a go program needs sudo to run in vscode?

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, sudo

I am coding a go program about network on my remote vscode server.
The program needs sudo to run, and I want to debug the program.
So how can I debug it in my remote vscode server?
Seems launch.json does not provide the sudo option

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#debug-a-program-as-root

```
{
...
    "asRoot": true,
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
...
}
```